# What is the clean way to integrate another service to django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, design-patterns, business-logic

I have a Django 3 application, using an LDAP service class, like this :

```
class LDAPService:
    def init(self, host: str, user: str, password: str, ssl: bool = True):
        ...
    def bind():  # The connection is done here, __init__ just sets values
        ....
    def create_ou(base: str, ou_name: str):
        ....
```

Where (or when) should I initialize the service to use it in views ? The bind step takes about 2 seconds to apply, I can not do it on every request. How can I keep an instance of this class shared, and not done every single time ? I may have a solution using singleton, and/or initializing it in like settings files, but i think there is a better way to do it.

I know in production, there may be multiple workers, so multiple instances, but i am ok with it.

Another question: How can everything above be done, with connections credentials from a database model (so not at django startup, but at anytime)

I am totally new to the django ecosystem, the things i have found about a service layer were all about django models. I want to do the same interface i would do for models in a regular service layer, but working on something else than django models.

I think the LDAP connection itself should not be there, only the CRUD methods, but i do not know where to place it, and how to make django interact with.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions :)

Comment: Right now i have renamed the service as _LDAPService, and initialised it in the file, as LDAPService, wich i use in my views.

Comment: It is a workaround, still asking the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [memoized factory function](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333701/using-singletons-in-python-django):

```py
def get_ldap_service() -> LDAPService:
  if not hasattr(get_ldap_service, 'instance'):
    get_ldap_service.instance = LDAPService(**input_from_somewhere)
  return get_ldap_service.instance
```

This is cleaner than a Singleton and allows for easier testability of the service class.

Additionally, it might be a better design to send the low-level connection logic to another class, say

```py
class LDAPConnection:
  def __init__(self, host: str, user: str, password: str, ssl: bool = True):
    ...
```

and then your service layer would take that as a dependency at run-time ([dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection))

```py
class LDAPService:
  def __init__(self, connection: LDAPConnection):
    self.connection = connection
  # CRUD operations
  def create_ou(self, base: str, ou_name: str):
    # Do operations via self.connection
    ...
```

This allows for different connections exposing the same interface.

You can build from these two ideas (dependency injection and caching) to get more complicated general structures in a maintainable way.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailled response. I think the factory function was what i was missing. I have one more question :) where do you initialise the LDAPSercice ? In my views i will use the service as an instanced class, where should I do the instance thing ? (It may be more a django question)

Comment: So you could either use the factory method for the connection or the service itself. I think in your case it will be simpler to just use it for the service itself and just call the method for each request